# Xubuntu 16.04 Xenial: How can I enable touchpad?

Tags: xubuntu, 16.04, touchpad

I've an Asus x540LA and my touchpad is seen by the system so:

[from /proc/bus/input/devices]

```
I: Bus=0018 Vendor=0b05 Product=0101 Version=0100
N: Name="FTE1001:00 0B05:0101"
P: Phys=i2c-FTE1001:00
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/INT33C3:00/i2c-1/i2c-FTE1001:00/0018:0B05:0101.0004/input/input6
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse1 event6 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=17
B: KEY=30000 0 0 0 0
B: REL=103
B: MSC=10
```

The touchpad is recognized as mouse. How i can fix it?